# C++ template Concept that requires specific parameter pack size

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Edit: This funcion have to check types one by one and return obj of any that will satisfy condition or nullptr.

```
template <typename... Args, typename = std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(Args) == 0)>()>
std::nullptr_t f() { return nullptr; }

template <typename T, typename... Args>
BaseClassOfAllArgs* f() {
    if (<some condition related to T...>)
        return new T;
    return f<Args...>();
}
```

This code works for me. But I wonder if is it possible to rewrite this code to use concept?
I mean something like this:

```
template <typename... Args>
concept NoArgs = (sizeof...(Args) == 0);
```

and then use it instead of std::enable_if(this code doesnt work)

```
template <NoArgs Args>
std::nullptr_t f() { return nullptr; }

template <typename T, typename... Args>
BaseClassOfAllArgs* f() {
    if (<some condition related to T...>)
        return new T;
    return f<Args...>();
}
```

EDIT: Here is working example of code after taking some tips from
guys in comments. After I added 'Base' to the template it turns out that EmptyPack concept is no longer needed. And First template naturally needs 3 typenames. However, I am not sure about this concept EmptyPack. Is it really making my program ill-formed no diagnostic required?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>
class X {};

class A : public X {};
class B : public X {};
class C : public X {};
class D : public C {};
class E {};

template<class T, class... Args >
concept DerivedsOfBase = (std::is_base_of_v<T, Args> && ...);

template<typename... Args>
concept EmptyPack = sizeof...(Args) == 0;

template<typename T>
std::nullptr_t f() {
    std::cout << "End of the types list" << std::endl;
    return nullptr;
}

template<typename Base, typename T, typename... Args> requires DerivedsOfBase<Base, T, Args...>
Base* f() {
    std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
    if (<some condition related to T>)
        return new T;
    return f<Base, Args...>();
}

int main()
{
    auto ptr = f<X, A, B, C>();
    auto ptr2 = f<X, A, B, D>();
    //auto ptr3 = f<X, A, B, E>(); // compile error
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Missing a `T` for the first overload.

Comment: @Barry No, he intends there to be no `T` in the first one I think.  He wants the zero-argument case to return `nullptr`, not the one-argument case.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I don't really know what OP intends, but the code as written has a `T` there but there is no type named `T` here. So either there needs to be a `T` declared somewhere, or the function needs to return `nullptr_t`.

Answer (score 2):

Any template parameter pack that only has valid instantiations for packs of size 0 makes your program ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

This applies to your first "working" example, as well as any practical variant I can think of using concepts.

From [the N3690 draft standard](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3690.pdf) [temp.res] 14.6/8:

> If every valid specialization of a variadic template requires an empty template parameter pack, the template is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

(I've seen that in many versions of C++, I'm just using a random draft standard as it showed up when I googled C++ standard pdf.)

Note that (a) your two `f` are overloads not specializations, and (b) what C++ programmers mean by "valid specialization of a template" and what the standard means are not quite the same thing.

In essence, pretty much any attempt at your concept will result in ill-formed, no diagnostic required programs.

To see the problem here, we'll reword the standard using negation:

> If (every valid specialization of a variadic template requires an empty template parameter pack) then (the template is ill-formed, no diagnostic required).

We can convert this "forall" into a "there exists".  "Forall X, P(X)" is the same as "Not( There exists X, Not P(X) )".

> Unless (there exists a valid specialization of a variadic template with a non-empty template parameter pack) then (the template is ill-formed, no diagnostic required).

If a variadic template has a requires clause that mandates the variadic template pack is empty, then no valid specialization of that template with an empty parameter pack exists.  So your template is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

---

In general, these kind of rules exist so that compilers can check if your code would always be nonsense.  Things like templates where no type parameter could make it compile, or packs that must be empty, are generally a sign that your code has bugs.  By making it ill-formed and not requiring a diagnostic, compilers are permitted to emit diagnostics and fail to compile.

An issue I have with the standard is that it is not just permitted to fail to compile, but it is permitted to compile a program that does literally anything.

Because the compiler is permitted to do this, and some optimizations in *other* cases actually result in this happening, you should avoid writing code that is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, like the plague.

---

A workaround is:

```
namespace implementation_details {
  struct never_use_me;
}
template <class=implementation_details::never_use_me>
std::nullptr_t f() { return nullptr; }

template <typename T, typename... Args>
T* f() {
  if (<some condition related to T...>)
    return new T;
  return f<Args...>();
}
```

another option is:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
T* f() {
  if (<some condition related to T...>)
    return new T;
  if constexpr (sizeof...(Args)==0)
    return nullptr;
  else
    return f<Args...>();
}
```

Comment: I don't see how that applies here. It's perfectly valid to evaluate the concept with a non-empty pack, and likewise constraints not being satisfied doesn't mean that the template is invalid.

Comment: @T.C. Name a valid specialization of the template the `requires` clause is on that does not require an empty template parameter pack.  That is the negation of the "ill-formed, no diagnostic required" requirement: "There exists a valid specialization of the variadic template with a non-empty parameter pack" else "the template is ill-formed, no-diagnostic required".

Comment: I kinda think the intent here is more about invalid specializations - of the form of the temp.res examples with `operator++`, `union X`, and `struct A` - that implementations could diagnose invalid specializations. There aren't any invalid specializations here.

Comment: @Barry As I mentioned, the standardese definition of "specialization" is different than our colloquial one.  If you read it as "instantiation" it is closer to non-standardese.  A "valid specialization" means a case where you have fixed template parameters passed in, and the result is "valid".  This requirement applies to both the primary template and the secondary ones (for classes).  (`=delete` is "valid", but a body that doesn't compile isn't)  For functions, there is overloading, not secondary templates.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need concepts for that, simply use `if constexpr`:

```
T* f() {
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Args) != 0) {
        if (<some condition related to T...>)
            return new T;
        return f<Args...>();
    } else {
        return nullptr;
    }
}
```

If you really want separated functions, you could always use overloading:

```
template <typename T> // no pack
T* f() {
    return nullptr;
}

template <typename T, typename Arg1, typename... Args> // one of more Args
T* f() {
    if (<some condition related to T...>)
        return new T;
    return f<Arg1, Args...>();
}
```

But of course you can always use `requires` expressions if you really want to keep the same logic you had with SFINAE. It should be possible (and enough) without a declared concept, but only with constraint:

```
template <typename T, typename...> // pack logically always empty
T* f() {
    return nullptr;
}

template <typename T, typename... Args> requires (sizeof...(Args) > 0)
T* f() {
    if (<some condition related to T...>)
        return new T;
    return f<Args...>();
}
```

Of course you can also wrap the condition inside a concept, but you gain very little using this technique in this case, since you still have to use the concept inside a require clause:

```
template<typename... Args>
concept nonempty_pack = sizeof...(Args) > 0;

template <typename T, typename...> // pack logically always empty
T* f() {
    return nullptr;
}

template <typename T, typename... Args> requires nonempty_pack<Args...>
T* f() {
    if (<some condition related to T...>)
        return new T;
    return f<Args...>();
}
```

The syntax `template<my_concept T>` will send `T` as the first parameter. You'll always get that parameter snet automatically, hence the need to put the concept in the requires clause.

Comment: Is the second `requires` clause necessary? Shouldn't the unconstrained one be less specialized and thus only selected if the other one isn't?

Comment: @NicolBolas I wasn't sure about that, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: See the below [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63563423/8372853). I think the concept solution is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, seems ok now, though I'm not completely sure.

Comment: @KrzysztofSommerfeld [I beg to differ](https://godbolt.org/z/hcdrhE)

Comment: If you will call f()<Derived1, Derived2, Derived3>() you will end up checking if condition only for Derived1 and Derived2; Added information that T needs to be base of all other types;

Comment: @KrzysztofSommerfeld that is a completely different problem then. I'm a bit confused why my answer did not solve what you posted before and now I struggle to see why classes with different bases have to do with the size of a pack.

Comment: This funcion have to check types one by one and return obj of any that will satisfy condition or nullptr. Added description.

Comment: And I know you can do this 10 different ways. I asked about how one can use concept for this if it is possibile. Like im my example with invalid code.

Comment: @KrzysztofSommerfeld I think I understood what you mean. Tell me if this is what you searched for.

Comment: Still no, but its easy to fix your idea. Now you will skip last type (becouse for last one Args is also 0) so you will return nullptr. But you can make EmptyPack requirment and use it this way. Then it works and looks nice and is easy to read.